# Listing connection strings for a cosmos db returns no results but listing keys works

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get the connection string for a cosmos db. In powershell when I do

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action listKeys -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts" -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $dbName | fl
```

I get a result showing the keys.

```
D:\> Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action listKeys `
>>                                -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts" `
>>                                -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" `
>>                                -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $dbName | fl

Confirm
Are you sure you want to invoke the 'listKeys' action on the following resource:
/subscriptions/(snip)/resourceGroups/example/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/myExampleDb
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y

primaryMasterKey           : (snip)
secondaryMasterKey         : (snip)
primaryReadonlyMasterKey   : (snip)
secondaryReadonlyMasterKey : (snip)



D:\>
```

However if I try to list the connection strings, [like the example in the documentation shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-account-with-powershell#list-connection-strings-powershell), I get no results

```
D:\> Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action listConnectionStrings `
>>                                -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts" `
>>                                -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" `
>>                                -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $dbName | fl

Confirm
Are you sure you want to invoke the 'listConnectionStrings' action on the following resource:
/subscriptions/(snip)/resourceGroups/example/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/myExampleDb
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y

D:\>
```

With a resource manager template, if I deploy the following resource manager template

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
      "dbName": { 
          "type": "string"
      }
  },
  "resources": [
  ],
  "outputs": {
      "listConnectionStrings": {
          "type": "object",
          "value": "[listConnectionStrings(resourceid('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', parameters('dbName')), '2016-03-19')]"
      },
      "listkeys": {
          "type": "object",
          "value": "[listKeys(resourceid('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', parameters('dbName')), '2016-03-19')]"
      }
    }
}
```

I get back from the outputs

```
{
    "listConnectionStrings":  {
        },
    "listkeys":  {
        "primaryMasterKey": "(snip)",
        "secondaryMasterKey": "(snip)",
        "primaryReadonlyMasterKey": "(snip)",
        "secondaryReadonlyMasterKey": "(snip)"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong that prevents the connection strings from being shown?

Comment: Do you have a MongoDB account? It looks like Azure's responses are contextual to the account invoking the query in regard to Cosmos, so if the account didn't need the connection string I don't think it'll give you one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Cosmo DB is a multimodel database service.
The connection string is only available for the database account using the **MongoDB** API.

> **[List Connection Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-account-with-powershell#list-connection-strings-powershell)**
>
> For **MongoDB accounts**, the connection string to
> connect your MongoDB app to the database account can be retrieved
> using the following command.

Below is the output of List Connection Strings action for CosmoDB using the MongoDB database account.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem and I tried various ways but this worked for me.

```
(Get-AzCosmosDBAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "RgName" -Name "accountName" -Type "Keys")."PrimaryMasterKey"
```

If you would like to get the connection string you could also use the below command

```
(Get-AzCosmosDBAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "RgName" -Name "accountName" -Type "ConnectionStrings")."Primary SQL Connection String"
```